# Exposing foreach on a class containing a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, foreach

```
class C_SQLSerResLibrary: IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<C_SQLServer, String>>
{
    private Dictionary<C_SQLServer, String> m_dicSQLResLibrary;
    // ...
    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<CSQLServer, String>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return(IEnumerator<KeyValuePair, String>>) m_dicSQLResLibrary. GetEnumerator();
    }
    // ... 
 }
```

I am attempting to Expose the foreach on the dictionary in a read only fashion.

Currently I am getting an Error CS0738 telling me that the class does not implement the interface member System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() return types do not match.

Comment: The return types appear to be different. Is this a typo? C_SQLServer and CSQLServer

Comment: Yep that was a typo on my part Ryan.  Nice catch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` implements `IEnumerable` non generic interface. It has a `IEnumerator GetEnumerator()` method as well, you've to implement that also in order to compile.

Try this

```
class C_SQLSerResLibrary: IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<C_SQLServer, String>>
{
    private Dictionary<C_SQLServer, String> m_dicSQLResLibrary;
    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<CSQLServer, String>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return m_dicSQLResLibrary.GetEnumerator();
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()//you missed this
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
 }
```

Comment: I think that the C-style cast can be omitted, doesn't it ?

Comment: @Seb That was in original code. It is redundant for sure. thanks for pointing I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks Loads.... I had added it previously but more compiler errors.  Since you reinforced I started to look at dependencies and found that IEnumerator is Not is System.Collections.Generic but Systems.Collections.  Added here to reinforce for me and alert other. Again big thanks from an ole C coder.